# FFT and Music Comparison

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, fft, data-mining, audio-analysis

I'm trying to play around with some music clustering algorithms, and I thought that using a feature vector consisting of basically a discretized fft (like discretize the frequencies) would be a good similarity measure. Would this even be useful? Do people know what some good audio similarity measures might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to decide whether you want *fingerprinting* (i.e. identity except for some distortion) or *similarity* (but not identity!) measures.

Also have a look at MFCC, bark scales and so on. There is plenty of literature out there. Go to Amazon, and grab a dedicated book on this topic.

Comment: I'm looking for similarity, but yes I've been reading up on the literature now much more. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I've you find something that lives up to this, keep me updated. The stuff I've tried so far was not too convincing for similarity, but primarily fingerprinting. There is an mpeg-7 feature extractor somewhere available, but even for those features that are meant to be used for similarity, it was unclear to me how to compute an actual similarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical cluster like a kd-tree or a hilbert curve before you discretize. A cluster reduces the dimension complexity and change the order of the input while a fft just transform it to waves.